# Access to vCenter Server (in private network) from the Internet through vSphere Client

Tags: port-forwarding, vmware-vcenter, juniper, srx

I have a vCenter server as a VM on my DPER710 in my internal network. DPE is connected to switch, switch is connected to JSRX, JSRX is connected to my ISP.

My vCenter Server is installed on Windows Server 2012 which has an access to the Internet (it goes through switch, JSRX and then reaches ISP and my VMS have the Internet connection.

But now I need different thing. My JSRX has a public static WAN IP address, lets say: 212.182.11.12/27.

How can I access my vCenter from the Internet? I would like to go home (server is at work), turn on vSphere client and be able to connect to vCenter Server and manage it from home. Is it possible? How can I do this? Do i need some port forwarding maybe? Which ports do I need to forward and how? Cheers!

Comment: How about using a VPN to get to the vCenter server or using something like RDP or LogMeIn to get to it? That's much less risky than exposing vCenter itself to the internet.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Questions on Server Fault must demonstrate a minimum understanding of the technology in question.  Otherwise, the post often **turns into a discussion forum**, instead of straight Q&A.  The best advice we can give you is to hire a consultant to help you out or do further research on the basics of this technology.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I access my vCenter from the Internet?

If you don't know, you shouldn't be doing it.  (And even if you do know, there are very few scenarios I can envision where it's actually a good idea.)

The proper answer is to setup a VPN so you can connect to your workplace network from anywhere in the world, and once in, connect to the vCenter server as if you were on the local network.

Comment: Ok - but I need to learn how to make it ;) So when I set up a VPN, lets say will use 'OpenVPN` in `routing` mode and it will give my machine where I have vCenter IP address of 10.8.0.1 then I need to NAT my public IP to the VPN IP? And after that will be able to connect with vSphere Client - how? Should I use OpenVPN on client side too? Please correct me if Im wrong here.

Comment: @mirx "How do I setup and configure a VPN" is a *completely* different question, which must have been asked here more than a few times, so I'd search for how to do that.  There must be a ton of tutorials on the internet at large, too.

Comment: Ok,foget the VPN setup I will search for it. But are you able to answer my other question: `when I set up a VPN, lets say will use OpenVPN in routing mode and it will give my machine where I have vCenter IP address of 10.8.0.1 then I need to NAT my public IP to the VPN IP? And after that will be able to connect with vSphere Client - how? Should I use OpenVPN on client side too? ` Im wondering about IP addresses, and the whole stuff. I set my forst VPN yesterday but only on my LAN

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you understand how a VPN connection works either. Please read up on the topic and test various set ups i.e. OpenVPN, IPSEC etc... When you understand how to implement a VPN and how it works, you will realise how to access your vCenter server remotely.

Tom